# How to separate words in a line from a text file into separate vectors?

Tags: c++

I am new to coding in C++. I am trying to lead a line from a text file. Each line contains two words. One word is the object, the other word is its color. So, one line could be Apple Red.

I am trying to read each line and store the first word (the object) into one string vector, and store the second word (the color), into another string vector. Any way of how to do this? Thanks.

I have tried using splitstring, and reading the line using a for loop until I find a space character that separates the two words, but I'm still confused.

Comment: One step at a time.  Have you created an `int main`?  Have you opened the file? Have you tried to read a line?  Have you tried to separate the line into words?  Have you tried to put the words in vectors?

Comment: If there are always two then `file >> word1 >> word2` could work. Otherwise `std::getline` and a stringstream could be used to split them up. If you search for how to split a string you'll find many examples here. If you have some code you should edit that into your question and explain the specific issue you're having so we can help solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Start at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and 
[std::vector::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (see the example on the page) and put together your first attempt at doing what you need. When you run into problems, edit your question to meet the requirements above so that help can be given.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    std::string item, color;
    std::string *ptrString = &item;
    while (file >> *ptrString)
    {
        if (s == &color)
        {
          Your_Code_To_Process_Item(item, color);
          item = "";
          color = "";
        }
        s = (s==&item) : &color : &item; // toggle what s points to
    }
}
```